# Производительность

Tags: производительность, cpu, gpu

Вопрос интересный, сколько примерно пригодится ресурсов, чтобы запустить 3000 браузеров хром?
Какие мощности нужны, в браузере будет открыта одна вкладка с видео

Comment: Скорее всего количество хэндлов переполнится раньше.

Comment: Подозреваю, что раньше всех закончится оперативка (хотя можно попытаться сделать огромную подкачку на SSD). Не знаю что с хэндлами, но если подразумевается 3000 воспроизведений видео, то, вероятно, процессор тоже очень быстро кончится на декодировании видеопотока (и/или видеокарта, если прокатит аппаратное ускорение)

Comment: ну видеокарта допустима)

Comment: ну есть варик на 128 озу, nvidia rtx3060, zeon 24 ядра 48 потоков

Comment: А ещё есть одна проблема - сеть. Может просто не хватить канала или гугл может настучать хостеру. Поэтому, по приблизительным оценкам, максимум 100 видео на сервер

Comment: там будут использоваться прокси, сеть 10 г\бит